# count most occurences with the WHERE from other table

Tags: mysql, select, count, multiple-tables

I have a movie DB to organize my collection but also I'm using it to learn more of mySQL. along the development I find bumps (plenty of them) and right now my problem is this:

Table `ACTORS`:

- id_actor
- name
- sex

Table `MOVIEACTORES`:

- id_movieactores
- id_movie
- id_actor

I want to count the TOP 5 (top10, top20 or whatever!) of actors with most movies and then the Top5 of actresses with most movies!

I have this:

```
  SELECT filmesactores.id_actor, 
         COUNT( * ) AS contagem
    FROM filmesactores
GROUP BY id_actor
ORDER BY contagem DESC 
   LIMIT 10
```

But this code doesn't discriminates actors from actresses. I feel the solution might be simple but with my knowledge is out of my reach right now. Anyone?

Comment: join the tables together ON the id of the actors so (id_actor = id_movieactores). Then add the WHERE clause

Comment: And how exactly do I do that? I'm still a noob!

Comment: Like this? SELECT filmesactores.id_actor, COUNT( * ) AS contagem
FROM filmesactores, actores
WHERE filmesactores.id_actor = actores.id_actor
AND actores.sexo = 'f'
GROUP BY id_actor
ORDER BY contagem DESC
LIMIT 10

Comment: is your table called filmesactores or movieactores?

Comment: I'm sorry the confusion... I have my table names in portuguese but to help people helping me I translate table names when asking the questions! I'll change my original table names to english to be lesst confusing and avoid these situations. sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by `sex, name` would separate actors' counts by gender, but since you want to apply the limit to each gender group (i.e. top 5 actors and top 5 actresses), perform two queries and UNION their results together:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS moviecount
FROM actors
JOIN movieactores ON actors.id_actor = movieactores.id_actor
WHERE sex = 'Male'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(id_movie) DESC
LIMIT 5

UNION

SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM actors
JOIN movieactores ON actors.id_actor = movieactores.id_actor
WHERE sex = 'Female'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(id_movie) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is usually faster than `COUNT(field)` in MySQL.

Comment: Hmm... and it also misses [NULLs in the counted field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html), I now realize. I'll change that...